# Bootstrap 3 scrollspy dont work

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, scrollspy

i have a problem with the famous scrollspy of Bootstrap 3, i am trying and trying and nothing work. i set the data tags in body and named the .nav in the navigation here is the code:

```
<body data-spy="scroll" data-offset="150" data-target="#navegacion">

        <div class="container">
            <!-- row 1 NAVIGATION -->
                    <header>
                            <nav class="nav navbar navbar-right navbar-fixed-top" id="navegacion" name="" value="" placeholder="" role="navigation">
                                <div class="navbar-header">
                                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navegacion">
                                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                    </button>

                                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                                        <img src="img/logo.jpg" alt="">
                                    </a>
                                </div><!--navbar collapse-->


                                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navegacion">
                                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" role="tablist">
                                        <li class="active"><a href="#aboutUs">ABOUT US</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#products">PRODUCTS</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#media">MEDIA</a></li> 
                                        <li><a href="#contactInfo">CONTACTS</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="index.html" style="color: rgb(65, 98, 170)">EN</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="">/</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="indexDE.html">DE</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div><!-- navbar collapse-->
                            </nav>
                    </header>
```

i think i set all the tags correctly in the body, here is a part of the code:

```
<!-- row 2 ABOUT US -->
                    <div class="row" id="aboutUs">
                        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4">
                            <h2><strong>ABOUT US</strong></h2>
                            <img src="img/news.jpg" width="264px" height="190">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-8">
                            <br/>
                            <br/>
                            <br/>
                            <p>Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32.</p>


                            <p>The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            <!-- row 2 ABOUT US END-->
```

When i am over the nav with the mouse cursor i see the hover effect but nothing changes, when i click the menu, for example #aboutUs the document go to the correct position where the secction #aboutUs are but not active the button.
anyone have the same problem?